# How can I update two rows in SQLite with Python?

Tags: sql, python-2.7, sqlite

I'm trying to update two rows in SQLite with Python:

```
Puntero.execute(
"UPDATE '{T}' set '{F}' = '{C}','{V}' = '{U}' where ID='{I}'"
.format(T = Tabl, F = fecha, V = Vendidos, U = id, C= Cantidad, I=id))
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: `"... where ID='{I}' OR ID='{I_other}'"`.format(... I=id, I_other=id_other)

Answer (score 1):

First, don't do it that way.  You are setting yourself up for SQL injections.  Use placeholders instead.

What you want is:

```
Puntero.execute(
   "UPDATE Tabl set fecha = :C, Vendidos = :U where ID=in(:I1, :I2)", 
      {"U": id, "C":Cantidad, "I1":id, "I2":otherid}
)
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris, now It is necessary to take into account that tablet, is a variable, that takes many values.

Comment: IN () can take any number.